# How do I get JSON result from jquery .ajax call in done()?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to use the newer .done() syntax for a call to .ajax(), but I don't see how to get the data returned from the server into my .done() function.  Here is my code:

```
function checkLink(element) {
    var resultImg = $(element).parent().parent().find("img");

    resultImg.attr("src", "/resources/img/ajaxLoad.gif");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/services/Check.asmx/CheckThis',
        data: '{somedata: \'' + whatever + '\'}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onFailure
    }).done(function () { success2(resultImg); });
}

function success2(img) {
    img.attr('src', '/resources/img/buttons/check.gif');
}

function onSuccess(data) {
    // The response from the function is in the attribute d
    if (!data.d) {
        alert('failed');
    }
    else {
        alert('hurray!');
    }
}
```

checkLink is called from a simple button push.  Both onSuccess() and success2() are firing just fine.  But... what I need is the "data" parameter from onSuccess passed to success2... or alternately, be able to pass "resultImg" to onSuccess (although I would prefer using .done instead of the deprecated method).  It seems I can either pass my own parameters, or access the JSON result from the AJAX call... but not both.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: .done(function(data) { console.log(data) });

Comment: Oh man... duh.  Neglected this because I wasn't enclosing success2 in a function, originally.  Fixed that and then missed this obvious next step.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can close over the resultImg variable:

```
function checkLink(element) {
    var resultImg = $(element).parent().parent().find("img");

    resultImg.attr("src", "/resources/img/ajaxLoad.gif");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/services/Check.asmx/CheckThis',
        data: '{somedata: \'' + whatever + '\'}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onFailure
    }).done(success2);

    function success2(data) {
        resultImg.attr('src', '/resources/img/buttons/check.gif');
        // do whatever with data
    }

    function onSuccess(data) {
        // The response from the function is in the attribute d
        if (!data.d) {
            alert('failed');
        }
        else {
            alert('hurray!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tmack, that probably works fine, but I think David had the preferred solution in his comment.